# CSS: Scissor-Cut images layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This is PNG, using PS:

> [image: Scissor-Cut]

And for images: [image: Scissor Cut 2]

See, how it is a kind of a trapezium, qith one side perpendicular, and the other titlted.

How can this layout be made in html/css, so that whatever imaage is forwarded to this div, it is always shown inside the trapezium, and it creates this fine ui.

How to create this kind of a shape in HTML/CSS?
Code after the accepted answer:

> `<div class="scissor"><img src="1.png" style="width:200px"></div>`

and css:

```
.scissor{       
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #FF6100;
    position: relative;
}
.scissor:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid #000; 
    border-right: 300px solid transparent;  
    display: block; 

}
span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to check `:before` and `:after` elements :)

Comment: Could you show an example? Or a tutorial link?

Comment: Sure! 
I think [that one](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) might help :)

Comment: Have you seen cards in android? 

So, there is a card and it has two parts: An image and the rest is text content. That's the image I want to cut to the trapezoid. I tried that tutorial but it didn't work. Here is the card: http://materializecss.com/cards.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pseudo element - `:before` or `:after`

```css
div{       
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #FF6100 url('http://www.hybworks.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/los-angeles-auto-repair-300x300.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
div:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 150px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 300px solid #fff;  
    display: block; 
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: 'segoe ui';
    color: #fff;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute; top: 10%; left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>D</span>
</div>
```

Example 2 - use `svg`

```html
<svg width="300" height="200">
  <polyline points="10, 10 300, 10 300, 100 10, 200 10, 100 10, 10" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(255,97,0)" fill="rgb(255,97,0)">
</svg>
```

Comment: Okay, one more quetion, you applied it to a div, and obviously, I can embed an image inside that div, but when I do, the image cracks out of the div, and doesnt occupy the space the range color does right now.

Comment: This works great for colors, and that solves one issue,but the image has also to be used. I can show you a png from psd, if you want?

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/d8cqfLyj/ or http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/f8o0vuLa/?

Comment: None of them, Sorry. I updated the question and included a screenshot of a psd.

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot for working on this problem. Thanks.